# how to handle List[Any] type in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can you guide me on handling `List[Any]` type in spark scala?

```scala
// my data 
val l1 = List(1,2,List(3,List(4,5,6),5,6,7))

// my required output
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

I am stuck in handling `l1` as it is `List[Any]` type.

I am not able to convert to `Dataframe` as it is `List[Any]` type.

Comment: perfect.i got the output but can you explain what the code is doing ?? what i used from your inputes - val foo = List(1,2,List(3,List(4,5,6),5,6,7)) def flat(ls: List[Any]): List[Any]= ls flatten { case t: List[Any] => flat(t) case c => List(c) } val res = flat(foo).distinct println(res) output printed - List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)